# if-else loop within a do while loop within another do while loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, do-while

When 'y' or 'Y' is inputted, I want the code to the prompt `System.out.print("Y/y or N/n: ");` starting from the first `do`,but instead the code will prompt `System.out.print("bad answer, try again: ");`, and I only want char besides y,Y,n,N to be the case.

The only code that follows is when 'n' or 'N' is entered, following `System.exit(0);`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      char ch;
      do
      {
         System.out.print("Y/y or N/n: ");
         do
         {
            ch = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
            if (ch == 'n' || ch == 'N')
            {
               System.exit(0);
            }
            else if (ch != 'y' || ch != 'Y' || ch != 'n' || ch != 'N');
            {
               System.out.print("bad answer, try again: ");
            }

         }
         while (ch != 'y' || ch != 'Y' || ch != 'n' || ch != 'N');
      }   
      while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using OR rather than AND, this condition will always be true:

```
else if (ch != 'y' || ch != 'Y' || ch != 'n' || ch != 'N')
{
    System.out.print("bad answer, try again: ");
}
```

By the way, you could simplify this to have a single do-while. If the answer is bad, just go on to the next iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon and check for ch and take AND.
Code could be like this:

```
else if (ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y' && ch != 'n' && ch != 'N')
{
       System.out.print("bad answer, try again: ");
}
```

**OR**

Remove semicolon and check for ch and take OR and finally take NOT.
Code could be like this:

```
 else if (!(ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y' || ch == 'n' || ch == 'N'))
 {
       System.out.print("bad answer, try again: ");
  }
```

Comment: +1 - I missed that semicolon! Might be worthwhile to explain to the OP what that semicolon causes to happen.

Comment: @AndyThomas the statement after 'if' runs no matter if the expression is true or not. because ; acts as a null statement after 'if' Thats why 'if' statement completes after ; and statements next to ; doesn't depend on if conditon.

Comment: In addition, the `{ System.out.println(...) }` is legal because Java allows a sequence of statements and declarations to be enclosed in braces, as a *block*. (BTW, the semicolon is technically an "empty statement.")